# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1 in arrays

Tags: java, arrays

hello @ all i have this probleme i have `two arraylist ta,ta1`
ta is an 1D `arraylist` contain many string objects in every frame i got only one object i want to forme a new `ArrayList` `ta1` witch take two or more object colectted from ta in `n=2` case we got 
 1with2 2with3 3with4 ....
example i have `n=2;`
ta [aa,bb,cc,dd]
ta1 will be [aabb,bbcc,ccdd]
i have tried with this

```
    String m = "";
    String h = "";
    int e = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= ta.size(); i++) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(tt.getText());
        while (n > 0) {
            String t = (ta.get(e + i));
            m = m + t;
            e++;
            n--;
        }
        ta1.add(m);
    }
    t3.setText(ta1.toString());
```

but its giving me that error in the title 
tanks for your help in advance

Comment: if you are starting index from `0` then must stop it at `< ta.size()`

Comment: please rearrange the code section so it will be clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `i<=ta.size()` is wrong, since the valid indices of `ta` go from 0 to `ta.size()-1`.

Second of all, in your while loop you assume that `e+i` is a valid index in `ta`, which is also an assumption you can't make without testing first that `e+i<ta.size()`.

First you should move

```
int n=Integer.parseInt(tt.getText());
```

to be before the for loop.

This way, changing

```
for (int i=0;i<=ta.size();i++)
```

to

```
for (int i=0;i<=ta.size()-n;i++)
```

will ensure that `e+i<ta.size()`.

You should also reset the relevant variables in the correct place. I think this should work :

```
     int n = Integer.parseInt(tt.getText());
     for (int i=0;i<=ta.size()-n;i++){
         int c = n;
         String m = "";
         int e = 0 ;
         while(c>0){
             String t=(ta.get(e+i));
             m=m+t;
             e++;
             c--; 
         }
         ta1.add(m);
     }
     t3.setText(ta1.toString());
```

Comment: TANK YOU SO MUCH THAT SOLVE THE PROBLEME

Comment: but still dont get the solution its giving me wrong solutions

Comment: @special Really? I tried it for  `ta [aa,bb,cc,dd]`. For n=2 I got `[aabb, bbcc, ccdd]`. For n=3 I got `[aabbcc, bbccdd]`. Isn't that the desired output?

Comment: yes not worked here for me mate 
i tried with this [habbaz,abdelkrim,habbaz,abdelkrim,habbaz,abdelkrim,abdou,krimou]
its giving me 
`[habbazabdelkrim, habbazabdelkrim, abdelkrimhabbaz, habbazabdelkrim, abdelkrimhabbaz, habbazabdelkrim, habbazabdelkrim, abdelkrimhabbaz, habbazabdelkrim, abdelkrimhabbaz, habbazabdelkrim, abdelkrimhabbaz, habbazabdelkrim, abdelkrimhabbaz, habbazabdelkrim, habbazabdelkrim, abdelkrimhabbaz, habbazabdelkrim, abdelkrimhabbaz, habbazabdelkrim, abdelkrimabd, habbazabdelkrim, abdelkrimhabbaz, habbazabdelkrim, abdelkrimhabbaz, habbazabdelkrim, abdelkrimabd, abddiego]`

Comment: @special I just tried that input for n=2 and got `[habbazabdelkrim, abdelkrimhabbaz, habbazabdelkrim, abdelkrimhabbaz, habbazabdelkrim, abdelkrimabdou, abdoukrimou]`. You are doing something wrong, since the size of the output should be the size of the input - n + 1.

Comment: Yeah this answer kicked my ass! +1

Comment: @Eran yes thats what makes me crazy i tried everything but always wrong output tanks for help i'll keep trying

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i=0;i<=ta.size();i++){
```

`ArrayList` is a 0 based index collection. That means that you go from `0` to `size - 1`. At the moment, you're going from `0` to `size`, which is causing the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: tank you so much for your help